# Nopcommerce The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

Tags: jquery, nopcommerce, antiforgerytoken

M getting this error too, but  for a change I am trying to submit the form using ajax. at that time it goes to error function and getting response as
" The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

I have tried different solutions to add this token value in ajax headers, along with the formdata to post. But none of them worked.

Kindly find the below code, which gets executed when click on New Account in register module.

```
var form = $('#registerForm');
                var dataObject = $('#registerForm').serializeObject();
                var token = form.find('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
                dataObject["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;
                var formData = JSON.stringify(dataObject);// store json string
                var headers = {};
                headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Customer/Register',
                    headers: headers,
                    data:  formData,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success=" + data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error=" + data);
                    }
                });
```

Have tried all permutation that I found in stackoverflow or from any nopcommerce blog but didn't get success. Please anyone if you have the solution to post the model along with this security token, do reply at the earliest.

Regards

Comment: can you put your controller code... so we can evealuate...

Answer (score 1):

You can collate formData and anti-forgery data token as following:

```
function addAntiForgeryToken(data) {
//if the object is undefined, create a new one.
if (!data) {
    data = {};
}
//add token
var tokenInput = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
if (tokenInput.length) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = tokenInput.val();
}
return data;
```

};

First call following function before "$.ajax({" line

```
addAntiForgeryToken(yourFormData);
```